# Get content from HTML element in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototype

I'm looking for a way to get the content of my div in my Rails view. I would like the literal HTML content, so only HTML and no Rails
I thought inner_html would work, but I get a RJS exception (TypeError:     $("content").innerHtml is not a function)

Does anyone know how I can get the content?
Thanks!

In my controller I use this code:

```
def save_test
    render :update do |page|
        page['content'].innerHTML
    end
end
```

Some more context maybe?
I get a HTML form (without the form tags themselves) and put it into a rails form.
What I want is that the user changes checkboxes, radiobuttons, fills out input fields etc and when the user saves, I want the literal changed content of the form as a string to save it to my database.
The reason for this is that the several provided forms differ a lot and it's only used as information, no calculations etc need to be done on it.
So my view looks like this:

```
form_remote_tag :url=>{:action => 'save_trainee_evaluation' do %>
<div id="content">
  <%= contract_trainer_trainee.evaluation_template %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag 'Opslaan' %>
```

Comment: Anyone? I've added some more context so it's clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are trying to use (i.e. `render :update do |page|` etc.) is for updating the HTML page (e.g. `page['content'].innerHTML = 'Thank you, we received your data.'`), not retrieving data from the page (that has to happen in the form submission).

Option 1) Simply use the form field data that has been submitted. (You didn't include an actual example, and I can't tell if there is other non-form content you want to save.) I would tend to do this by converting the `params` hash to a JSON string and saving that in a text field in the database. E.g. `@evaluation.content = params.to_json`.

Option 2) Include the full div HTML in the form post by copying it into a hidden field when the form is submitted. (You might need to do some encoding of the HTML string before you put it into the hidden field.) Using your example code as a starting point:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url=>{:action => 'save_trainee_evaluation'}, :html => { :onsubmit => "$('content_inner_html').value = $('content').innerHTML;" } do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'content_inner_html', :id => 'content_inner_html' %>
<div id="content">
  <%= contract_trainer_trainee.evaluation_template %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag 'Opslaan' %>
```

Then, in the controller, you'll have the HTML block in `params[:content_inner_html]`.

Comment: Yes, you have identified the problem.  

The HTML is generated by Rails based on some state information (perhaps from an ActiveRecord object).  I'm completely unclear why the HTML itself must be stored instead of the (possibly changed) state information, since the form HTML can be recreated at any time by rendering the view with the current state info.

Answer (score 0):

Use `page["content"].innerHTML`.

Comment: How exactly? Because right now I'm working with a remote_function and I'm calling page['content'].inner_html in my controller

Comment: I still get the same alert with the same error when I do this: 

def save_test
   render :update do |page|
     page['content'].innerHTML
   end
  end

I want to put that content in a variable...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code please, rather than put it in a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, that wasn't very clear indeed. I've put it in my start post